# 3 Questions regarding restoring the backup of whatsapp from Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google, restore, google-drive

My phone Lenovo K53a48 stopped working on the 7th of June. I have a backup of all my WhatsApp messages until the 6th of June on Googe Drive. I installed WhatsApp on an Xperia M2. After I signed in with my phone number the question about if I want to restore my backup from my Google Drive came up. However, it required 9,3GB and the phone has a total internal memory of 8GB. I then bought a memory card of 32GB and put in inside my phone. However, the same message appears, so I understand there is no option to restore and save my WhatsApp history on the memory card. Could you confirm that, please?

Furthermore, If I uninstall the WhatsApp application now, do I have the option to install it on the memory card and so restore my backup on the memory card where there is plenty of space?

Finally, the last question. If I uninstall now WhatsApp without choosing to restore the backup but also without selecting the opposite, will I have the option to do it the next time I install WhatsApp or is it now or never?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Leo

Answer (score 1):

> so I understand there is no option to restore and save my WhatsApp history on the memory card. Could you confirm that, please?

Like any other apps, it is possible to save Whatsapp on the memory card. If whatsapp is installed on the internal storage, then its default location is the internal storage. If it is installed on the SD card, then it saves everything on the SD card.

> If I uninstall the WhatsApp application now, do I have the option to install it on the memory card and so restore my backup on the memory card where there is plenty of space?

Yes. If your phone allows for the installation of apps on the SD card, then there won't be any problem.

> If I uninstall now WhatsApp without choosing to restore the backup but also without selecting the opposite, will I have the option to do it the next time I install WhatsApp or is it now or never?

What do you mean by "If I uninstall now WhatsApp without choosing to restore the backup but also without selecting the opposite"?

When you unistall Whatsapp, the backups are still present in Google Drive. If you then install the app again, it will ask you to restore them.
However, [note](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/) that:

> Every time you create a Google Drive backup using the same Google account, the previous Google Drive backup will be overwritten. There's no way to restore an older Google Drive backup.

Comment: I did some more research and it comes out that it is not possible to install whatsapp on the SD card.... https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/21068307/

Comment: Could you suggest something? Thank you very much in any case for your answer! I really apreciate it!

Comment: My WhatsApp's files (media, documents, etc) are on my SD card (possibly because my phone is rooted and direct apps to save data on it).